# Display Data in form of Table row by clicking single or multiple Checkboxes in Django

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, django, html-table

I am working on Django framework and stuck in a bad situation. I have my Data table that is fetched from database and displaying in a table form. At the end of the table there are multiple checkboxes which is used to customize the data and display the only data for which I have clicked on single or multiple checkboxes. After clicking on checkbox / checkboxes data have to display in table form.

```
    <head>
         
         <script>
              function getvalues()
              {
                   let selected = new Array();
                   var chckbox = document.getElementById("tab1");
                   var selchk = chckbox.getElementsByTagName("input");
                   for(var i=0; i<selchk.length;i++)
                   {
                        if(selchk[i].checked)
                        {
                             selected.push(selchk[i].value);
                        }
                   }
                   if(selected.length> 0)
                   {
                        document.getElementById("displayvalues").innerHTML= selected;
                   }
                   
              };
         </script>
              
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <table border = "1">
         <tr>
              <th> ID </th>
              <th> NAME </th>
              <th> EMAIL </th>
              <th> SALARY </th>
              <th> PHONE   </th>
         </tr>
         {%for getdata in EmployeeDetails %}
         <tr>
         <td> {{getdata.id}}</td>
         <td> {{getdata.empname}}</td>
         <td> {{getdata.email}}</td>
         <td> {{getdata.salary}}</td>
         <td> {{getdata.phone}}</td>
         </tr>
         {% endfor %}
    </table>
<table id = "tab1">
     <tr>
         <td> {%for display in EmployeeDetails %}
          <input type="checkbox" value="{{display.salary}}" /> {{display.salary}}
                         {% endfor %}
                    </td>

     </tr>
</table>

     <input id="but1" type="button" value="display records" onclick="getvalues()"/>     
          <b id="displayvalues"></b>
    </body>
```

[As you can see in image when I click on any checkbox It just gives me checkbox value not the entire row. I want entire row result by clicking on single or multiple checkboxes and it should display in form of table pertaining rows.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZ9zd.jpg)

Kindly Help me to get out of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your javascript function needs to find more than the checkbox value.
You also need the rows with the corresponding salary.

To achieve this, I would add a class corresponding to the salary on every row. Then I would use JavaScript's QuerySelectorAll to get every row with the class corresponding to the salary, hide every row and show the matching rows.

I added a "a" before every class because they can't start with a number.

```js
function getvalues()
              {
                   let checkboxes = document.getElementById("tab1");
                   let table = document.getElementById("table");
                   var selchk = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
                   
                   let selected = [];
                   
                   for(var i=0; i<selchk.length;i++)
                   {
                        if(selchk[i].checked)
                        {
                             selected.push(selchk[i].value);
                        }
                   }
                   
                   var query = "#tr";
                   
                   for(var j = 0; j < selected.length; j++) {
                      query = query + ", .a" + selected[j];
                   }
                   
                   if (query !== "")
                       var rows = table.querySelectorAll(query); // Every element having a class corresponding to the salary you want
                   else var rows = [];
                   
                   table.querySelectorAll("tr").forEach((r) => r.style.display = "none");
                   
                   rows.forEach((r) => { // For every row r
                       r.style.display = ""; // Hide r
                   });
                   
              };
```

```html
<table border = "1">
         <tr>
              <th> ID </th>
              <th> NAME </th>
              <th> EMAIL </th>
              <th> SALARY </th>
              <th> PHONE   </th>
         </tr>
         <tr class="a12">
         <td> 1</td>
         <td> test</td>
         <td> tset@test</td>
         <td> 12</td>
         <td> 0606060606</td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="a22">
         <td> 2</td>
         <td> test2</td>
         <td> tse2t@test</td>
         <td> 22</td>
         <td> 0606060626</td>
         </tr>
    </table>
    
<table id = "tab1">
     <tr>
         <td>
          <input type="checkbox" value="12" /> 12 </td>
         <td>
          <input type="checkbox" value="22" /> 22 </td>
     </tr>
</table>
<table border = "1">
         <tr>
              <th> ID </th>
              <th> NAME </th>
              <th> EMAIL </th>
              <th> SALARY </th>
              <th> PHONE   </th>
         </tr>
         <tbody id="table">
         <tr class="a12">
         <td> 1</td>
         <td> test</td>
         <td> tset@test</td>
         <td> 12</td>
         <td> 0606060606</td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="a22">
         <td> 2</td>
         <td> test2</td>
         <td> tse2t@test</td>
         <td> 22</td>
         <td> 0606060626</td>
         </tr>
         </tbody>
    </table>
    
     <input id="but1" type="button" value="display records" onclick="getvalues()"/>     
          <b id="displayvalues"></b>
```

ISOLATED TEMPLATE FOR CLARITY :

```
 <table border = "1">
     <tr>
          <th> ID </th>
          <th> NAME </th>
          <th> EMAIL </th>
          <th> SALARY </th>
          <th> PHONE   </th>
     </tr>
     {%for getdata in EmployeeDetails %}
     <tr class="a{{ getdata.salary }}">
     <td> {{getdata.id}}</td>
     <td> {{getdata.empname}}</td>
     <td> {{getdata.email}}</td>
     <td> {{getdata.salary}}</td>
     <td> {{getdata.phone}}</td>
     </tr>
     {% endfor %}
</table>
<table id = "tab1">
     <tr>
         <td> {%for display in EmployeeDetails %}
             <input type="checkbox" value="{{display.salary}}" /> {{display.salary}}
                     {% endfor %}
         </td>
     </tr>
</table>

      <input id="but1" type="button" value="display records" onclick="getvalues()"/>     
      <b id="displayvalues"></b>


 <table border = "1">
     <tr>
          <th> ID </th>
          <th> NAME </th>
          <th> EMAIL </th>
          <th> SALARY </th>
          <th> PHONE   </th>
     </tr>
     <tbody id="table">
     {%for getdata in EmployeeDetails %}
     <tr class="a{{ getdata.salary }}">
     <td> {{getdata.id}}</td>
     <td> {{getdata.empname}}</td>
     <td> {{getdata.email}}</td>
     <td> {{getdata.salary}}</td>
     <td> {{getdata.phone}}</td>
     </tr>
     {% endfor %}
     </tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: dear @Arthur, very appreciable answer and it starts working. my actual question was that I have two tables let say table 1 and table 2. In table 1 I have displayed the information and in table 2 I want to display the information on which checkboxes I have selected

Comment: Dear @Arthur, I have shared the 2nd image for which I want the output, please consider that image if u can give that output

Comment: I see what you are trying to achieve, but please post your answers as comment and not as edits

Comment: I updated my answer to answer your question. You need to create 2 tables : one should remain unchanged, the other will be filtered by the javascript function.

Comment: Dear @Arthur, thank you for your answer, last question is I want to display one table at one time but after selecting checkbox or checkboxes 2nd table should be displayed after selecting checkboxes values.

Comment: Then you need to add some style on the second table in order to hide it. When you click on your button to filter, you have to remove this style. The proper styling is style="display: none;", and the javascript to achieve this is "document.getElementById('myElement').style.display = '' // This removes the current display style, if the display was none then it isn't none anymore and appears ". Happy coding